# Method is not firing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm trying to hide a button only when a certain URL is being displayed in a UIWebView. This is the code I'm using to do so:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    NSString *full = [request.URL absoluteString];

    NSLog(@"Test back button, URL is: %@", full);

    if ([full isEqualToString:@"testexample.com/"]) {
        _backButton.hidden = YES;
        return NO;
    } else {
        _backButton.hidden = NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

For some weird reason, the buttons never get hidden and the NSLog never fires. I made sure to write this in the correct view controller, and also double checked that my button's outlets are connected. Does anyone know what may be causing this?

Comment: Yeah, first suspicion would be that you never set your web view delegate pointer.

Comment: I don't think I did, do you know how I do that? Sorry I'm very new to Xcode.

Comment: Right click on the web view, and that will bring up the black window. You should see "delegate" there with an open circle (if it hasn't been connected yet) next to it. Drag from that circle to the controller icon down at the bottom of the scene.

Comment: Cool thanks, I just did that and it is already connected to View Controller.

Comment: And did you change the method to what I show in my answer?

Comment: Yes sir, I switched it and ran into a few errors, let me check what they were and ill comment back on your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such method that you have in your question. The method is:

```
webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
```

Comment: I changed it to the method you provided. It now looks like this: `- (BOOL)webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: { code}` But, I'm getting 2 errors and 2 warnings. 
Warning 1:'shouldStartLoadWithRequest' used as the name of the previous parameter rather than as part of the selector.

Warning 2:  'navigationType' used as the name of the previous parameter rather than as part of the selector

Comment: @OralB, It shouldn't be implemented like I show in my answer, that's just the name of the method. It should be: -(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType

Answer (score 1):

Just check in .h file that you have set **UIWebViewDelegate** and your view controller you have set `webView.delegate = self;` check this is implemented properly.

I had gone through same issue in past.

Comment: Oh it doesn't look like it is, I don't have anything in my ViewController.h except for `@interface ViewController : UIViewController`. I just added `webView.delegate = self;` and got the error: Unknown type name webView.

Comment: But for some reason all of my other code and buttons work fine on the web view.

Answer (score 0):

did you set the `UIWebView` delegate to be your view controller?

Comment: I just right clicked my web view, and the delegate is indeed the view controller.

Comment: Well I thought that it did, sorry. I'm unsure if it is, how can I check?

Comment: in interface builder, when you select the web view, if you goto the connections tab you should see delegate. that should be linked to "File's Owner"

Comment: Okay thanks. It looks like it is set to the view controller rather than the files owner, I don't see a "files owner" in the little bar under the view either.